# Does system restore restore desktop files and folders

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

I have a user profile which has files moved from the desktop to the network and deleted. Will system restore restore user profiles as well such that my desktop files will be back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the FAQ by Microsoft ([link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/System-Restore-frequently-asked-questions)), System Restore only monitors system files, programs, registry settings and certain types of executables.

If your files were executables, System Restore should restore them. However, it will not restore documents, photos, etc.